# Creating an SQLite database using a text file from a URL / Postcode to NUTS1 mapping

Tags: python, sqlite, text-files, urllib

I've had a read through the other SQLite questions on here - but unfortunately haven't been able to get to the bottom of my question (part 1, that is).

So my question is in 2 parts:

(1) I'm trying to get data from a text file, separated by commas, into an SQLite database using the sqlite3 python module. My attempted code is below - though I'm getting an error which says "parameters are of unsupported type" - I presume that means the way I've defined my parameters is incorrect (given that some contain both letters and numbers), though I've had a play around with a number of formats and can't seem to crack the right combination

Sample URL: http://prod1.publicdata.landregistry.gov.uk.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pp-monthly-update.txt

Sample code:

```
# Connect to the database (or create if it doesn't exit)
conn = sqlite3.connect("LandRegistry.db")

# Define the cursor
c = conn.cursor()

# Create a table
def create_table():
    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PricePaidData(
    unique_ID TEXT, 
    price_paid INT, 
    deed_date TEXT, 
    postcode TEXT,
    property_type TEXT,
    new_build TEXT,
    estate_type TEXT,
    address_1 TEXT,
    address_2 TEXT,
    address_3 TEXT,
    address_4 TEXT,
    address_5 TEXT,
    address_6 TEXT,
    address_7 TEXT,
    transaction_category_1 TEXT,
    transaction_category_2 TEXT)""")

# Populate the database
def update_table():
    url = "http://prod1.publicdata.landregistry.gov.uk.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pp-monthly-update.txt"
    data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    c.executemany("""INSERT INTO PricePaidData (
    unique_ID,
    price_paid,
    deed_date,
    postcode,
    property_type,
    new_build,
    estate_type,
    address_1,
    address_2,
    address_3,
    address_4,
    address_5,
    address_6,
    address_7,
    transaction_category_1,
    transaction_category_2) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);""", data)
    conn.commit()


create_table()
update_table()
c.close()
conn.close()
```

(2) Not sure if this is the appropriate place to put this question - but I'd also like to map the addresses from here (I imagine the postcodes are most helpful in doing so) to NUTS1 regions (as defined in the below link). A previous question mentioned an R package which might be helpful here - I'd preferably like to do this in Python. I presume the best way of doing so would be (a) download a link of prefix postcodes within each NUTS area (to a csv?), (b) run some sort of look-up of the first 2 letters of the postcode in the SQLite database to the NUTS csv and return the appropriate region in a separate column. Any pointers to ways I can do this would be appreciated!

NUTS1 regions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NUTS_1_statistical_regions_of_England

Thanks in advance all!

Comment: An easy way to import CSV data into a table is by using the sqlite3 shell program: https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#csv_import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, `urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()` just returns the data returned by fetching the given URL as a big blob of bytes (Or maybe a string? I'm not sure). You have to split that up into lines, and use a CSV parsing library (One comes with python) to split each of those lines up into values to insert.

Or you can get the same effect with a few lines of shell script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
url="http://prod1.publicdata.landregistry.gov.uk.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pp-monthly-update.txt"
curl -s -O "$url" && sqlite3 -batch -csv LandRegistry.db <<EOF
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PricePaidData(
    unique_ID TEXT, 
    price_paid INTEGER, 
    deed_date TEXT, 
    postcode TEXT,
    property_type TEXT,
    new_build TEXT,
    estate_type TEXT,
    address_1 TEXT,
    address_2 TEXT,
    address_3 TEXT,
    address_4 TEXT,
    address_5 TEXT,
    address_6 TEXT,
    address_7 TEXT,
    transaction_category_1 TEXT,
    transaction_category_2 TEXT);
.import pp-monthly-update.txt PricePaidData
.quit
EOF
rm -f pp-monthly-update.txt
```

This uses curl to download the CSV data into a file and the sqlite3 shell's CSV import functionality to load the contents into the `PricePaidData` table (after creating said table if it doesn't already exist.)